# Which is better in Symfony2: render Controller or include Template?

Tags: php, symfony, model-view-controller, twig

I develop university site with Symfony2. Besides I'm almost newbie in Symfony.

Index page consists of several blocks: news, events, photos, etc. All objects are fetched from webservices, so no DB is used directly.

I wonder which is better:

1. Fetch all news,photos,.. objects in DefaultController:indexAction
   and pass them to index.html.twig as arguments
2. Call render(controller(News:block)) in index.html.twig. And
   NewsController in turn fetches objects and renders
   news_block.html.twig.
3. Some other way?.. I actually use the second way but I think it is not good.

Please give me advice.

Comment: the second approach let you do re-use the block-code in other page/place.

Comment: depends on your opinions, but as a purest Id rather handle all the data manipulation in the controller and pass it in.  If the application was large, or got large, it would be much easier to handle.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There cannot be a perfect obsolete answer for this question. Both ways are equally standard ways of coding in Symfony. Its a decision based approach which matters a lot.

1. Fetch all news,photos,.. objects in DefaultController:indexAction and pass them to index.html.twig as arguments -> when the data you are displaying/loading for the page is relatively less or belongs to one single module/feature. This way you have a simple process - route -> controller -> twig. Simple but sweet way of coding.
2. Call render(controller(News:block)) in index.html.twig. And NewsController in turn fetches objects and renders news_block.html.twig. -> Use this approach when your twig/page is rendering a lot of components or requires a lot of heavy lifting in one action. This will help you a lot in maintaining the code, as each part of your twig is rendered seperately using seperate controllers. Plus, this will also improve the site UX performance a little bit, because the twig is initially rendered with bare minimum information and then each individual component renders itself seperately using own controllers.

Comment: I was confused a little bit by the long way of request:
indexAction - index.twig - newsListAction - mews_block.twig. I wondered if it could be shorter.
So now I've got it. Thank you for the answer.